# MOSFET have big voltage drop across Drain-source?

Tags: mosfet

I tried with IRL544 and IRF540N (N channle mosfets)by connecting load(12v-0.45A)as this image.
[image]

Above image is only to show my schamatic.

When ieasure voltage across drain and source it is around 3.7V(both).
As i expected it should be lower then that. Is there something wrong with schematic?

Comment: What is the characteristics of the load. (cant find IRL544 description on google). The mosfet is not in saturation region as you see. It's because of the load's vi characteristics. Any info on that will help.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Oh. Okay how are you avoiding the problem?

Comment: Actually i hve a jumper connected to gate and switching it manually but when i suppose it to connect high, i actually connect it to drain pin(i forget it has only high voltage when mosfet is off).

Comment: What was the solution?